# Boolean parameter values in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, boolean-operations

I'd like to understand how a PowerShell script handles boolean parameter values.

I have a script with 4 parameters, 2 of which are boolean variables. When I run the script & set one of these parameters to $False, the script still thinks this variable is set to $True.

**Version 1: BooleanTest.ps1 (using BOOLEAN parameters)**

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)][string]$param1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=2)][string]$param2,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=3)][bool]$param3,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=4)][bool]$param4
)

write-output $param1, $param2, $param3, $param4
```

Running this script from the command prompt returns the following:

```
>BooleanTest.ps1 -param1 "String1" -param2 "String2" -param3 $True -param4 $False
String1
String2
$True
$True
```

I've also tried adjusting this script to use switch parameters instead:

**Version 2: BooleanTest.ps1 (using SWITCH parameters)**

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)][string]$param1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=2)][string]$param2,
    [switch]$param3,
    [switch]$param4
)

write-output $param1, $param2, $param3, $param4
```

Running this version from the command prompt returns:

```
>BooleanTest.ps1 -param1 "String1" -param2 "String2" -param3:$True -param4:$False
String1
String2

IsPresent
---------
     True
    False
```

Based on these trials, I have the following questions:

- In Version 1, why is the fourth variable incorrectly being returned as $True when I declared it as $False?
- In Version 2, why is the "IsPresent" list being returned?
- How does the switch statement work? After passing in the variable, do I need to run additional code to assign the True/False value, or can I use the parameter as is?

I've read various several help & troubleshooting articles, but there doesn't seem to be any clear documentation on passing boolean values to a script. I would appreciate any information that would help me understand the proper techniques to apply in this situation.

My System Set-Up:
OS: Windows 10
PowerShell Version: PowerShell 7.1.5

Comment: Version 1 works for me, as expected. Output: `String1
String2
True
False`

Comment: The `IsPresent` thing is interesting, normally you use a switch parameter just like a boolean parameter in code. The difference is just in passing explicit `$false` value. E. g. you can use `switch` parameter in boolean context like `if( $param3 ) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: [Switch parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#switch-parameters). @zett42 _Switch parameters are of type `SwitchParameter`, which **implicitly converts to Boolean**._

Comment: @JosefZ, yes. I just have never outputted a switch parameter _as-is_, so its default output surprised me.

Answer (score 6):

### Version 1

This works for me. I get the following output:

```
String1
String2
True
False
```

I'm not sure what's going on when you run this, but this is the output expected from what you provided.

---

### Version 2

You are not using [bool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean?view=net-5.0) types, you are using [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.switchparameter?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) types. `switch` behaves much *like* a boolean but is *not* a boolean. When determining truthiness, ultimately the value of `IsPresent` is considered and not the default behaviors of truthiness. When the `switch` value is `$false` or not provided, it evaluates to `$false`. If the `switch` value is `$true` or is provided, it evaluates to `$true`.

> **Note:** I stated `IsPresent` is considered when comparing `switch` to `bool`. This is an oversimplification and technically incorrect, though you can look at `IsPresent` to understand how the determination would be made. If you want a more advanced explanation, read on.
>
> The actual reason and "secret sauce" behind the magic is because the `SwitchParameter` type (`[switch]` is a [type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_accelerators?view=powershell-7.1) for `SwitchParameter`) [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.switchparameter?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#operators) the `==` and `!=` comparison operators, and casting operators between `bool` and `switch` both ways. These overloads allow `switch` and `bool` to functionally behave like the same type during comparisons and allows implicit conversion ([typecasting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)) between the two, despite being completely different [ValueTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype).

Most of the time the differences between `bool` and `switch` won't matter. You use them the same way in comparisons 99% of the time, save for maybe code intended for debugging when you would actually need to inspect the properties of either.

They also differ in terms of default output, when writing to the console `switch` has a different *display-formatter*, which formats the output as a table showing `IsPresent` by default, unlike the `bool` type. This, however, is a very minor difference.

Where they *mainly* differ is in when and how you use them.

---

### When to use `switch`

`switch` is best for using with parameter definitions. They are idiomatic to PowerShell in this way and you don't need to provide a `$true` or `$false` value with the parameter. You simply specify them or don't like so:

```
BooleanTest2.ps1 -param1 "String1" -param2 "String2" -param3
```

This will output the same as your current invocation of your version 2 boolean test. Although as you discovered, you *can* provide the `$true` or `$false` value which is handy when you need to conditionally provide the `switch` based on another condition.

### When to use `bool`

Conversely, using `bool` for a parameter is less common and is not considered idiomatic. You have to provide both the parameter and the value the same way you would for any other type. In practice, this generally isn't a problem as long as it's documented but it's something to consider. `bool` is most often used anywhere else in a script you aren't defining function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/107mafm/why_does_my_boolean_parameter_always_say_true/?onetap_auto=true) for an explanation.

When running from the command line with your script if you pass -param4 $False it should work.
When running from the powershell_ise where you are prompted and you enter $False it does not work as it is treated as a string which is evaluated as true.

Comment: Please avoid simply linking to external sites containing the explanation of your answers, since they may not always exist later, and include a complete answer here.